# Bitbucket Sync branch equivalent in Github

Tags: github, bitbucket

Bitbucket's web interface provides a nice 'Sync' option for branches. It actually merges master-branch in any selected branch from the UI.

I have not found, is there a similar option in Github web interface?

Comment: You can create a pull request and select which branch should be merged into which one. Is that what "sync" does?

Comment: @mkayaalp, actually no. I would like a possibility to merge master-branch if it went forward into some other branch created from an old master.

Comment: You mean this, but then for branches in the same repo? https://twitter.com/github/status/1390382527588798477

Comment: @jesshouwing, yes, does GitHub have something for the branches from the same repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such option in GitHub Web UI at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually not different from a local merge of master/develop into your working branch and using local sync is better also.

Merging locally has the advantage to revert merge back easily by keeping the unmerged branch in the server. You can delete the local merged one and pull back the unmerged one from the server. In this way, you can try lots of merge strategies and use the one which suits best to you.

Comment: Yes, local merge reaches the same goal, but has a disadvantage that more files can become updated in the working folder resulting in longer build time. So the merge from Web UI can be an advantage.

Comment: @Fedor, but you should consider Github Actions run time credits are limited and every sync on the web might cause a new extra pipeline run that consumes your credits.

Comment: I see, still, I would like to have such an option in Web UI.